# Sort list of function using sort with key in racket

Tags: sorting, lambda, scheme, racket

```
(functionsort functionlist value)
```

functionsort takes 2 argument, list of functions and a single value.
return same list of function sorted in increasing order when given "value".

for example : here is my list of function

```
(define myfunctions (list (lambda (x) (+ x 3)) 
                     (lambda (x) (- 100 x))
                     (lambda (x) (* x 2))))
(define fs 
    (function-sort myfunctions
                   5))
```

should return the following

```
((first fs) 6)   ; (first fs) is (lambda (x) (+ x 3))
9
((second fs) 6)  ; (second fs) is (lambda (x) (* x 2))
12
((third fs) 6)   ; (third fs) is (lambda (x) (- 100 x))   
94
```

here is what i got so far:

```
define (function-sort functions value )
   (map (lambda (y) (y value)) functions))
```

which compute the value , 9 94 12 un sorted.
and I try to use

```
 (sort myfunctions #:key (function-sort myfunctions 10) <)
```

which gives me error

```
. . sort: contract violation
expected: (any/c . -> . any/c)
given: '(13 90 20).
```

Any suggestion ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt was on the right track, but you have to pass an adequate argument for `#:key` - we want to *evaluate* each function with the given value, and the`sort` procedure will sort the input list of functions according to the result returned by each function, when applied to the value. Try this:

```
(define (function-sort functions value)
  (sort functions < #:key (lambda (f) (f value))))
```

For improving performance on large lists with expensive functions, pay attention to Will Ness' suggestion: using `#:cache-keys? #t` will prevent multiple evaluations for the same argument, and in fact will be similar to what you intended to do with `map` in the first place (that is: precomputing the values *before* sorting). Consider:

```
(define (function-sort functions value)
  (sort functions < #:cache-keys? #t #:key (lambda (f) (f value))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(define myfunctions (list (lambda (x) (+ x 3)) 
                          (lambda (x) (- 100 x))
                          (lambda (x) (* x 2))))

(define fs (function-sort myfunctions 5))

((first fs) 6)
=> 9
((second fs) 6)
=> 12
((third fs) 6)
=> 94
```

Comment: Looks like it's your 999th answer on the [tag:scheme] tag? Par-tay!!! :) :)  -- a little nitpick here, if I may: probably best to use "decorate-sort-undecorate" idiom here to avoid functions' multiple evaluations for the same argument - as it turns out, Racket does this for us automatically when `#:cache-keys? #t` is specified in the `(sort ...)` call.

Comment: @WillNess nice suggestion! I updated my answer. I wonder, why isn't `#t` the default value for `#:cache-keys?` ?

Comment: I guess because `(lambda (x) x)` is the default `#:key`. I.e. it'd be entirely superfluous on very cheap keys.